# placeholder text not shown until clicked in compose OutlinedTextField

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have the following composable OutlinedTextField

```
@Composable
fun EmailEntry(
    shouldShowLabel: Boolean = false,
    onEmailEntered: (emailText: String) -> Unit) {

    var emailText by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    OutlinedTextField(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        singleLine = true,
        value = emailText,
        label = {
            if(shouldShowLabel) {
                Text(text = "Email")
            }
        },
        placeholder = {
            Text(text = "Email Address")
        },
        onValueChange = { newText ->
            emailText = newText
            onEmailEntered(emailText)
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email)
    )
}
```

However, the placeholder text doesn't show until the user clicks in the textField. I want to placeholder to display, then disappear when the user starts typing.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use both `label` and `placeholder` for what you expecting. Rather use a `Column` to wrap and inside that use another `Text` above `OutlinedTextField` as `label`. Here is the example:

```
@Composable
fun EmailEntry() {
    var emailText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Column() {
        Text(text = "Email")
        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            singleLine = true,
            value = emailText,
            placeholder = {
                Text(text = "Email Address")
            },
            onValueChange = { newText ->
                emailText = newText
            },
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email)
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: That did not work as expected. I would like to display the placeholder text. When the user starts typing it will disappear. In XML you could set the `hint` and get the expected behavior.

Comment: Edited, I put value field empty that's why it wasn't editable. Try now, it works exactly how `hint` works.

Comment: Thanks, That works, only if I remove the following: `            label = {
                if(shouldShowLabel) {
                    Text(text = "Email")
                }
            },
`

Comment: `You can not use both label and placeholder for what you expecting.`
Is there a way around it? I find wrapping it with a column really janky. Why isn't that the default behavior anyways?

Comment: AFAIK Label is not TextFields responsibility.  
@polendina